# Visual Studio dotnet core socket error during test discovery

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xunit, .net-core

I am creating a test project in Visual Studio. It builds, but fails to discover the tests in the project with the following error:

```
Unable to start C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
dotnet-test Error: 0 : [ReportingChannel]: Waiting for message failed System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

The full text of the error log can be seen here [at this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4417)

Here is my project.json file

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",

"dependencies": {
    "MyProject.Web": {
        "target": "project",
        "version": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta3-build3402",
            "xunit.runner.console": "2.2.0-beta3-build3402",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.2.0-beta3-build1187"
},

"testRunner": "xunit",

"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": "dnxcore50",
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "type": "platform",
                "version": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
},
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
}
```

The frustrating part is that up until yesterday this project had been working fine for a couple of weeks with 40 or so tests.  Any ideas how to get past this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: So please up arrow the question to see if we can get someone to pay attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I installed dotnet-test-xunit package and the VS Test Explorer now sees and runs my tests.  Resharper still can't find them, but I imagine we will be going through this a few more times before the whole MSBuild dotnet core thing gets sorted out.

Comment: Specifically I found this link got me going:   https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-test-xunit/

Comment: Yep.  That is the one I am currently using

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue after upgrading packages(nuget) and then got it resolved by this thread(order is matter if you target for core and netxxx) https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/900